# Gradle - How add a flat directory on svn as gradle repository

Tags: gradle

I'm using Gradle as my build tool. I want to use a flat directory on our SVN as repository. Of course, it needs credentials too. My build file work with local directory using **flatDir** but I don't know how to configure it to read from a url.

Comment: What is the url and protocol for the svn repository?

Comment: url and protocol: https://svn.example.com on HTTPS